# Recall different data names inside loop

Tags: r

here is how I created number of data sets with names data_1,data_2,data_3 .....and so on 
for initial 
dim(data)<- 500(rows)  17(column) matrix

```
for ( i in 1:length(unique( data$cluster ))) {
  assign(paste("data", i, sep = "_"),subset(data[data$cluster == i,]))
}
```

upto this point everything is fine

now I am trying to use these inside the other loop one by one like

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  data<-  paste(data, i, sep = "_")
}
```

however this is not giving me the data with required format 
any help will be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use `data <-  get(paste(data, i, sep = "_"))`

Comment: thank you for so quick response.
I am expecting the output also as a matrix such that

dim(get(paste(data, i, sep = "_"))) <- matrix(m*n)

above code is not helping

Comment: Your second for loop tells me that you are trying to combine the first 5 datasets into one? You can either write `rbind(data_1, data_2, data_3, ...)` or first store your datasets in a list and use `do.call(rbind, dataList)` to combine your datasets. I hope I am understanding this correctly.

Comment: @R_Learner If you need help with a specific problem, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: '@ Joris Meys' Thanks a lot for your suggestion from next time I will definitely keep these standards in Mind.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me give you a tip here: Don't just assign everything in the global environment but use lists for this. That way you avoid all the things that can go wrong when meddling with the global environment. The code you have in your question, will overwrite the original dataset `data`, so you'll be in trouble if you want to rerun that code when something went wrong. You'll have to reconstruct the original dataframe.

Second: If you need to split a data frame based on a factor and carry out some code on each part, you should take a look at `split`, `by` and `tapply`, or at the `plyr` and `dplyr` packages.

### Using Base R

With base R, it depends on what you want to do. In the most general case you can use a combination of `split()` and `lapply` or even a `for` loop:

```
mylist <- split( data, f = data$cluster)
for(mydata in mylist){
  head(mydata)
  ...
}
```

Or

```
mylist <- split( data, f = data$cluster)
result <- lapply(mylist, function(mydata){
  doSomething(mydata)
})
```

Which one you use, depends largely on what the result should be. If you need some kind of a summary for every subset, using `lapply` will give you a list with the results per subset. If you need this for a simulation or plotting or so, you better use the `for` loop.

If you want to add some variables based on other variables, then the `plyr` or `dplyr` packages come in handy

### Using plyr and dplyr

These packages come especially handy if the result of your code is going to be an array or data frame of some kind. This would be similar to using `split` and `lapply` but then in a way Hadley approves of :-)

For example:

```
library(plyr)
result <- ddply(data, .(cluster),
                function(mydata){
                  doSomething(mydata)
                })
```

Use `dlply` if the result should be a list.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.
Infact probably in a most precise way.
Thanks a lot.:)